# Print data in a file in python

Tags: python

I have a python proxy server which basically prints every data Passes through it. Here is a part of the code :

```
 for sock in reader:
                data = sock.recv(BUFSIZE)
                if not data:
                    return
                if sock is socket_dst:
                    socket_src.send(data)
                else:
                    socket_dst.send(data)
                    print(data)
        except socket.error as err:
            error("Loop failed", err)
            return
```

And it prints data like this :

```
x14\xe4\xd5\xc3\x84dt\xc5\xee\xc7\xf2\xab\x87\x96P\xe1\xbf\x81`\xc5\xb3\xd8\x9f\xe3Z\x1e7/\x17v\xcat\xdf\xc1Lu\x1d\xad|:\xc
```

But I want to print everything passes through the server as it is.If images passes through it should write the bytes inside of a given file . Every text and and encodings and all other characters.
I have tried :

```
with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

And it just writes the first buffer of the data flow do keep it open till the whole script runs or how do I write all the Buffer data in a single file?

Comment: Do you store a file type somewhere? How are you going to detect the file type?

Comment: I want to store the data in a file . There are tools like cyber chef to detect file types.

Comment: You could try using a logger with a FileHandler instead of writing straight to file: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: My goal is capture everything . binaries. Can I do that with logger?

Comment: It "shows me errors", but the exact error messages somehow didn't seem like an important detail to include?  Seriously?  I'm going to make a wild guess that it's something like "expected str, not bytes", and that you simply need to open the file in `'wb'` mode so that it can accept binary data.

Comment: You aren't going to get what you want in the way you think you want it. Period. You are asking for a raw socket of arbitrary chunks of bytes to magically produce multiple, distinct files of the correct format, despite not having any foreknowledge of what you're receiving, or where the file boundaries are. That's untenable.

Comment: @jasonharper you were right . And I opened the file with 'wb' mode but it writes only the first buffer the rest it ignores . I want to write all the buffer data in a single file.

Comment: @g.d.d.c  I am using it on an App that doesn't encrypt data traffic. And I know that the app will transmit few texts , images and few more bytes not so much. I am doing this on my phone to myself.

Comment: Encrypted or not doesn't matter in this case. Consider the scenario where the data that comes off your socket is: `TEXTTEXT...<imagedataforsomebytes>...MORETEXT`. If your `read(buffsize)` reads the first block of text and half the image, _how do you know_? Which bytes are text, and which bytes are image? How can you tell you need to read the rest of the image? When are you done reading the image? The tool you are using is insufficient for the task you've described.

Comment: You are right .Yeah I could use tools like Wireshark. But this code I have here puts everything in order. Each buffer size is 2048 max and images it compresses to less than 100kb.

Comment: What I mean is the app doesn't transmit text and bytes together . It  receive or send an Image file then texts then other stuff.